# Can I clean-up / delete local Composer directory?

Tags: composer-php

I have about 800 json files with a total of 1 GB in composer\Local\repo\https---repo.packagist.org

What's the purpose of those files? What might happen if I just remove them?

composer\Local\files\ contains 80 MB only.

[image]

Comment: "What might happen" - why not try it? Looks like caching files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply clear the cache with `composer clear-cache`.